# how to write projection query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, apache-nifi

I have a json object like this.

```
                [{
            A:"XXX",
            B:"ss",
            C:"qee",
            Z:[ {e:"p",f:"q",g:"r"},
            {e:"w",f:"x",g:"y"},
            {e:"s",f:"t",g:"u"}]
            },
            {
            A:"XYX",
            B:"ss",
            C:"qee",
            Z:[ {e:"p",f:"q",g:"r"},
            {e:"w",f:"x",g:"y"},
            {e:"s",f:"t",g:"u"}]
            },
            {
            A:"YYY",
            B:"ss",
            C:"qee",
            Z:[ {e:"p",f:"q",g:"r"},
            {e:"m",f:"n",g:"o"},
            {e:"s",f:"t",g:"u"}]
            }]
```

now i want to run a query on basis of A,e,f. and i want resultant object to have `A,B,C,Z{}` (but for Z, only object that got matched.

so if i give value as `{A: "XXX", Z.e:"s", Z.f:"t"} i get`

```
            {
            A:"XXX",
            B:"ss",
            C:"qee",
            Z:
            {e:"s",f:"t",g:"u"}
            }
```

I am not sure how to write projection for this?

Comment: *but for Z, only object that got matched.* How it can be measured?

Comment: I have modified my question to explain what i was asking.